# Problems about getting the value of xmlns which is generated dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I hava a xml like this:

```
 <w:l1 xmlns:w="20130815"><w:l2 w:val = "test"/><w:l1>
```

if I want to access the element `w:l2`,I need know the value of the `xmlns` for `w`,but the value of `w` is dynamic.

How should I get the value of `w` from the xml?

Comment: What about using `Descendants` without caring about `xmlns`?

Comment: @KingKing - that would only work when `l2` is the only tag inside `l1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
XElement l1 = ....  // load or parse, then find the relevant tag

XNamespace nsW = l1.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w");

XElement l2 = l1.Descendants(nsW + "l2").First();
```

Comment: Didn't know about `GetNamespaceOfPrefix` method. Nice. For OP: complete parsing can look like `var value = (string)l1.Element(nsW + "l2").Attribute(nsW + "val");`

Comment: thanks for your help,I am a beginner for C# xml,i still have a question: if the node "l1" is just one child node in the xml file,when i load the xml file,i can get the root node,but how should i get the l1 node?i didn't know the value of "w".@Henk Holterman

Comment: When it's the only element then it is the root. `l1 = XElement.Parse(...);` or `doc = XDocument.Parse(...); l1 = doc.Root;`

Comment: Sorry，what i said is probably not clear enough，so that you misunderstood，i meant the “l1" is neighter the only element nor the root，in this case，how should i get the “l1”  @Henk Holterman